# How to get correct size or bounds of UIView in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Hi i'm having trouble to apply gradient color to my `UIView`. It is *correctly applied*, but the color *bounds varies* with horizontal & portrait orientation.

if I set correctly on Portrait orientation, then the gradient view's bounds are not changed when I flip the device to horizontal.

So, How to get correct constraints and size of the `UIView` for both horizontal and portrait device orientation?.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

**Code I have tried:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var viewBar: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        viewBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.0, height:2.0)
        viewBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        viewBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame.size = self.viewBar.bounds.size

        self.viewBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

**Coding output:**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` the layout haven't happened yet, so you got the wrong frame, move the `gradient.frame.size = self.viewBar.bounds.size` to either `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` or `viewWillAppear:` so that your `gradient` gets the correct frame.

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    gradient.frame.size = self.viewBar.bounds.size
  }
```

Comment: Not Working.. same output is came... i try this method also ... `gradient.frame = viewBar.frame `  
and
 `gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewBar.frame.width, height: viewBar.frame.height)`

thankz for your help man.. :) :) :D

Comment: You can try call `self.view.setNeedLayout()` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after `super.viewDidLoad()` and try again

Comment: thankz man your code is works very well... if **DISABLING THE SIZE CLASSES** thank lot :) happy here !! :D

Comment: when i use `self.view.setNeedLayout()` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after `super.viewDidLoad()` also works very well if i not **Disabling the Size Calsses**  the gradient applied whole **UIView** ... thanks for your help :) :D

Comment: Glads to help :d you don't need to disable the size classes it will affect other phone layout

Answer (score 2):

Check your device orientation in viewDidLayoutSubViews using this method.

```
+(NSString*)checkDeviceOrientation
{
    NSString *deviceOrientation;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {

        deviceOrientation = @"landscape left mode";
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        deviceOrientation = @"landscape right mode";
    }
    else{
        deviceOrientation = @"potrait mode";
    }
    return deviceOrientation;
}
```

Then in viewDidLayoutSubviews
call this function like this,

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubview
{
if(IS_PHONE4)
if([self.checkDeviceOrientation isEqualtoString;@"landscape right mode"])
{
   NSLog(@"Get your view size%@",self.view.frame.size.width);
}

if(IS_IPHONE5)
if([self.checkDeviceOrientation isEqualtoString;@"landscape right mode"])
{
   NSLog(@"Get your view size%@",self.view.frame.size.width);
}
.....

}
```

Also remember to put these constants in any file, you want.

```
#define IS_IPAD             (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE           (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE4          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f || IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width == 480.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE5          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f || IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE6          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0 || IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS      (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0 || IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width == 736.0f)
#define IS_RETINA           ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

I am unfamiliar with Swift code but hope, it will help you.

Comment: This question is tagged "swift". Your solution may have value, but is not written in the language requested by OP, so it's off-topic. Please provide an answer in Swift. Thank you.

Comment: I knew, I am unfamiliar with swift. I just wanted to explain how to do it. A person who worked with swift and Objective C, it is very easy for him to understand it.

Comment: @ WasimSafdar  , wow great man... i will do this in swift..  thankzz lot :)

Comment: @ MohanSigh, please remember to rate my answer. :)

Comment: **@ WasimSafdar** yeah i already rate it but stack ask i at least have 15 reputation for putting rates to answers... so when i reach that 15 then i will do this... :) :D

Comment: Okay, no problem :).